# subprocess permission denied

Tags: python, windows, permissions, subprocess, python-3.5

I was looking into how python can start other programs on windows 10, I was on stack overflow and someone said that:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\Edvin\Desktop', 'C:\\Example.txt'])
```

should do it, so I changed the locations so it is specific to me and there was an error which was `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`.

Does anyone know how to grant permission for python to open the file?

I've tried:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\Edvin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows'
                 '\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\Notepad.exe'],
                 'C:\\Users\\Edvin\\Desktop\\Example.txt')
```

but this comes up with `TypeError: bufsize must be an integer` error.

Comment: don't worry it's clear, I didn't read well enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that you're trying to launch your desktop as a program. With a text file as an argument.

This is not allowed because you're not allowed to execute the desktop (because it can't be executed).

```
subprocess.call(["command here", "arguments here"])
```

if it's an `exe` use

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\...\\program.exe', 'argument'])
```

if it's a python script use

```
execfile('file.py')
```

Comment: even a file on the desktop?

Comment: so what should i put in the arguments?

Comment: I tried to leave the arguments blank and put in the correct command and there was a new error OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: this is my exact code import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\Edvin\Desktop\Example.txt', '']) and im trying to open a text file that is on my desktop as you can probably see

Comment: open it with what? notepad ? because a txt in not a program. You can try and find Notepad.exe or something similar and then use `subprocess.call(['C:\\...\\Notepad.exe', C:\\Users\Edvin\Desktop\Example.txt'])`

Comment: oh wow im stupid... but still when i do              import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\Edvin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad.exe'], '')      it comes up with a popup that is syntaxError and it says unicode error codec cant decode bytes in position 81-82: malformed \N character escape

Comment: try using \\ instead of \

Comment: oh sorry the comment didnt load properly and o you mean for all of them?

Comment: possibly, try it. Backslashes are a pain ;)

Comment: ok i tried that and youll be happy to know that there is a new error.. this time TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Comment: Oh, and your code isn't exactly right, you need `call(["the link to notepad", "the file to open here"])

Comment: do you mean the file path for the text file?

Comment: yes. A program (here, notepad) needs arguments (here, the name of the file) to work. Just like Python functions need arguments

Comment: sorry im confused can you do an example

Comment: is this what you mean...import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\Edvin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\Notepad.exe'], 'C:\\Users\\Edvin\\Desktop\\Example.txt')

Comment: almost, `subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\Edvin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Micros‌​oft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\Notepad.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Edvin\\Desktop\\Example.txt']) `

Comment: thanks so much it kind of worked but if it says the system cant find the file? even though it is there and ive checked the paths and everything seems correct

Comment: is it called Example.txt or example.txt ? please post the error

Comment: just found out that notepad is .lnk but that hasnt solved my problem i really dont know how the file isnt found if ive copied the path from file explorer

Comment: its Exampe.txt.

Comment: ok i recopied the path and now its just access denied again xD  and im not trying to open the desktop this time

Comment: ive gone into the file properties and i have full control of the file as i am admin have any ideas?

Comment: The OP is using Python 3, so there is no `execfile`, plus that's not how a script should be executed anyway. A script generally expects to be executed in its own process. Use `subprocess.call(['python', 'file.py'])`. It's ok to just use `'python'` for the executable on Windows because `CreateProcess` first searches in the application directory where it finds "python.exe", but you can use `sys.executable` instead if you prefer the fully-qualified path.

Comment: Wow thats so much easier thanks but I dont understand the sys.executable is that a completely different function?